# SUM from a preview query (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query from `Uploads` table:

```sql
select
    Customer as Customer,
    max(Week) as 'Max Week',
    count(distinct(POS)) as 'Total POS'
from Uploads
where year = 2022
group by Customer;
```

and returns this:

| Customer | Max Week | Total POS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | 3 | 65 |
| Customer B | 5 | 27 |
| Customer C | 3 | 33 |

This table has an additional column named `Inventory` and I want to know the `SUM(Inventory)` but with the weeks filtered before.
For example:

| Customer | Max Week | Total POS | Inventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | 3 | 65 | 456 |
| Customer B | 5 | 27 | 123 |
| Customer C | 3 | 33 | 2345 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using `Row_Number` like this

```sql
SELECT t.[Total POS],
       t.customer,
       t.week MaxWeek,
       t.SumInventoryPerWeek SumForMaxWeek
       FROM (
select
    Customer as Customer,
    Week as week,
    count(distinct(POS)) as 'Total POS',
    SUM(Inventory) SumInventoryPerWeek,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Week DESC) rw
from Uploads
where year = 2022
group by Customer,Week
) t
WHERE t.rw=1
```